# Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(java.lang.String[], int)'

Tags: android, xamarin, maui, .net-maui

I have tried to request on App's class to request the READ_CONTACTS permissions but throws an exception
Exception
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(java.lang.String[], int)' on a null object reference'

```
{
    public App(SignalrMessenger signalrMessenger, ChatServicesSettings chatServicesSettings, ContactServices contactServices)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        

        if (!IsPermissioGranted(Android.App.Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts))
        {
            RequestPermission(Android.App.Application.Context as Activity, new[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        MauiApplicationServices.WasDatabaseUpdatedOnStartUp = contactServices.SynchronizeDbWithLocalContacts().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        MainPage = new MainPage(signalrMessenger,chatServicesSettings);//new AppShell();
    }
    public bool IsPermissioGranted(Context ctx, string permission)
    {
        return ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ctx, permission)== Permission.Granted;
    }
    public async Task RequestPermission(Activity activity, params string[] permissions)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity, permissions, 0);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

So I wonder if there is possibly a way to ask for permission in an Activity and inject a service OnCreate method? since the default ctor is called in the MainActity app initialization

Comment: decided to use the ServiceCollection and... then us e a static field on a static class to access said services...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnCreate` method will be triggered as expected in `MainActivity` class.

You can ask for the permission inside `MainActivity` instead of `App` class.

#### Sample code

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // We have permission, go ahead and use the camera.
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera },0);
        }
    }

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
         base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Comment: This fix resolved a problem I had when upgrading target to Android Api level 33

Answer (score 0):

You can pass MainActivity as argument in App methord

step 1: Initialise a Activity variable in App methord

```
     public App(SignalrMessenger signalrMessenger, ChatServicesSettings 
             chatServicesSettings, ContactServices contactServices,Activity activity)
```

Step 2 : Create Constructor with in the App Methord

```
       public App(SignalrMessenger signalrMessenger, ChatServicesSettingschatServicesSettings, ContactServices contactServices,Activity activity)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.activity = activity;
    .........
    ........}
```

Step 3: Now call App Methord with sutable Parameter

```
    App( signalrMessenger, chatServicesSettings,contactServices,MainActivity.this)
```

{
public App(SignalrMessenger signalrMessenger, ChatServicesSettings chatServicesSettings, ContactServices contactServices)
{
InitializeComponent();

```
    if (!IsPermissioGranted(Android.App.Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts))
    {
        RequestPermission(Android.App.Application.Context as Activity, new[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    MauiApplicationServices.WasDatabaseUpdatedOnStartUp = contactServices.SynchronizeDbWithLocalContacts().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    MainPage = new MainPage(signalrMessenger,chatServicesSettings);//new AppShell();
}
public bool IsPermissioGranted(Context ctx, string permission)
{
    return ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ctx, permission)== Permission.Granted;
}
public async Task RequestPermission(Activity activity, params string[] permissions)
{
    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity, permissions, 0);
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

}